# Load chrome extension using java programming

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have create a download manager like **IDM** and I want to install chrome extension.
As you see when you install IDM it automatically add chrome extension in it.
I want to do it like that whenever mine Downloader install it will automatically add chrome extension same as IDM.
I'm new in software development so, how to do that I'm using java programming.

I checked IDM folder and found **.crx** file which mean this is chrome extension.
And I think IDM load extension from this folder to chrome.
But according to my search Google disable to install chrome extension out of Chrome web store then how IDM do it.

Any suggestion which things I need to do that ?

**UPDATE:**

I try to install it using `preference JSON` but its not working. 
I followed a method which is described [here.](http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/crx/docs/external_extensions.html)
 please check out this link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extension Installation using Registry Entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699134/google-chrome-extension-installation-using-registry-entries)

Comment: on this question they said you can only provide the chrome web store url of that extension. so user download and install it but IDM is not doing like this it has already **.crx** file in local machine and it install automatically

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't use this crx.

Comment: But just a few hour ago I install IDM and it automatically install chrome extension. Only option appear when I run chrome is "enable or disable this extension". If you see the `chrome://extension` it show this extension is install by third party.

Comment: The answer in the linked question explains what happens. There's no "but". IDM extension's manifest.json provides `update_url` and Chrome uses it to download the extension.

Comment: So, how can I do that for my extension that will be added to chrome automatically. WHat method I used to do like IDM.

Answer (score 0):

After facing a same problem, I found this [Google article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/)  which will help you to Load Chrome extension from outside.

> An extension that is not installed from the Chrome Web Store is known as an external extension. For developers who want to distribute an extension as part of the installation process for other software, or for network admins that want to distribute an extension throughout their organization, Google Chrome supports the following extension installation methods:
>
> Using a preferences JSON file (for Mac OS X and Linux only) Using the
> Windows registry (for Windows only) Both ways support installing an
> extension hosted at an update_URL. On Windows and Mac, the update_URL
> must point to the Chrome Web Store where the extension must be hosted.